# getElementById('variableName') loop breaking

Tags: javascript

```
/*
 * Helper Functions
 */
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  for(var key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}

/*
 * Create div(s) from Object with style properties
 */
Layer.prototype.createEl = function(object, target, className) {
    count = 1;
    for(e in object) {
        var newElement = document.createElement("div")
        newElement.id = e;
        setAttributes(newElement, { 
          "class" : className, 
          "data-name" : e, 
          "data-order" :  count
        });

        for(x in object[e]) {
            newElement.style[x] = object[e][x];
        }

        target.appendChild(newElement);
        count++;
    }
}


if (typeof authorized !== "undefined" && app.identify()) 
{
    app.createEl(app.identify().containers, document.body, "layerFrame");
    for(e in app.identify().containers) {
        app.createEl(app.identify().framing, document.getElementById(e), "framework");
    }
}
```

app.identify() returns a JSON object. The .containers portion looks like this:

```
"containers" : {
    "master" : {
        "position" : "fixed",
        "width" : "150px",
        "height" : "200px",
        "bottom" : "0px",
        "right" : "100px",
        "background" : "yellow"
    },
    "response" : {
        "display" : "none",
        "position" : "fixed",
        "width" : "150px",
        "height" : "200px",
        "bottom" : "0px",
        "right" : "100px",
        "background" : "teal"
    }
},
```

The area that breaks is the 3rd last line of code where I'm calling the app.createEl function. Specifically the getElementById(e) portion.

If I console.log 'e', it returns "master" and "response" as expected.

And if I hard-code in document.getElementById("master") instead of document.getElementById(e), everything works as I want it to.

But when I run it with 'e', I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null"

typeof(e) = a string, why does this break when I use getElementById(e)?

### **ANSWER**

Not sure if this is relevant to anyone, but the issue was calling the function
createEl(object, target, className) 
and passing in document.getElementById() for the target argument directly. All I did was assign document.getElementById() to a variable, then called createEl() and passed in that variable for the target argument:

```
for(e in app.identify().containers) 
{
    tmp = document.getElementById(e);
    app.createEl(app.identify().framing, tmp, "framework");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to see what is coming with `e` ?

Comment: does it break if you hardcode `document.getElementById("repsonse")` ( instead of `master`) ?

Comment: Are you converting the JSON to an object via JSON.parse at some point?

Comment: @collapsar - yeah that works fine. Doesn't break..

Comment: @sumanBogati - e returns a string each pass through the loop. First pass e = master, second pass e = response

Comment: @collapsar - No, the id being issued is from the JSON object and is unique. I'm looping through the object for(e in object), and assigning the id = e. Target is the destination for the newly created DIV to be appended to.

Comment: ah, sorry, i was not looking carefully enough at the code. deleting my erroneous comment, sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Well, man, I've created a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Uk9cR/) simulating what you're saying, but the document.getElementById(e) is working pretty well here.</del>

<del>If you show us what is the "app.identify().framing" thing, I can try to simulate what you're doing.</del>

EDIT:

After you showed what's the framing thing, I've updated my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Uk9cR/1/), and it's still working pretty well. Probably, your app.identity() is not the Javascript Object you expected.

```
var json =  {
    "containers" : {
        "master" : {
            "position" : "fixed",
            "width" : "150px",
            "height" : "200px",
            "bottom" : "0px",
            "right" : "100px",
            "background" : "yellow"
        },
        "response" : {
            "display" : "none",
            "position" : "fixed",
            "width" : "150px",
            "height" : "200px",
            "bottom" : "0px",
            "right" : "100px",
            "background" : "teal"
        }
    },
    "framing" : {
        "header" : {
            "width" : "150px",
            "height" : "100px",
            "background" : "pink",
            "display" : "none"
        },
        "contentTop" : {
            "width" : "150px",
            "height" : "100px",
            "background" : "purple"
        },
        "contentBottom" : {
            "width" : "150px",
            "height" : "100px",
            "background" : "green"
        },
        "footer" : {
            "width" : "150px",
            "height" : "100px",
            "background" : "blue"
        }
    }
};

function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  for(var key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}

var createEl = function(object, target, className) {
    count = 1;
    for(e in object) {
        var newElement = document.createElement("div")
        newElement.id = e;
        setAttributes(newElement, { 
          "class" : className, 
          "data-name" : e, 
          "data-order" :  count
        });

        for(x in object[e]) {
            newElement.style[x] = object[e][x];
        }

        target.appendChild(newElement);
        count++;
    }
}

createEl(json.containers, document.body, "layerFrame");
for(e in json.containers) {
    createEl(json.framing, document.getElementById(e), "framework");
}
```

Comment: .framing is just referencing another member of the JSON object:  "framing" : {
   "header" : {
    "width" : "150px",
    "height" : "100px",
    "background" : "pink",
    "display" : "none"
   },
   "contentTop" : {
    "width" : "150px",
    "height" : "100px",
    "background" : "purple"
   },
   "contentBottom" : {
    "width" : "150px",
    "height" : "100px",
    "background" : "green"
   },
   "footer" : {
    "width" : "150px",
    "height" : "100px",
    "background" : "blue"
   }
  },

Comment: thanks for the effort in your answers man. Banging my head on this for a long time, and turned out to be something stupid. The problem in my code was calling createEl() using document.getElementById(e), right in the function call. All I did was assign document.getElementById(e) to a variable, then called createEl() using the variable. I guess I needed to be using the result of document.getElementById, instead of the call itself. Many thanks again for the effort in trying to help. Much appreciated!